# How to output results of an Azure Function running locally to a file as well as the Console

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I need to have an Azure Function running locally output to the Console as well as a file so I can monitor the results.  Right now it only outputs to the Console.  I don't see where I can modify the output.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: You can use Azure blob storage output binding - sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp. If you want to monitor the results you can add application insights and log custom events that will appear in your AppInsights instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-functions-supported-features

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at the [Azure Functions binding concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings).

As as @Milen mentioned in the comment, you can use Azure Blob storage output binding. Then you will store the outputs to the blob file.

Just go to your `function.json` file to add the storage blob output binding.

```
{
  "name": "myOutputBlob",
  "type": "blob",
  "path": "samples-workitems/{queueTrigger}-Copy",
  "connection": "MyStorageConnectionAppSetting",
  "direction": "out"
}
```

Then you can use it in your code, here is the JavaScript code

```
module.exports = function(context) {
    context.log('Node.js Queue trigger function processed', context.bindings.myQueueItem);
    context.bindings.myOutputBlob = context.bindings.myInputBlob;
    context.done();
};
```

For more details, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=javascript#example).